# how to pass column name dynamic in query?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

My query

```
col_name=('parole_state', 'hiv_treatment_state', 'receiving_hiv_treatment', 'mental_health_provider', 'employed', 'parole', 'employer_state')

qs_new = Model_Name.objects.all().values(col_name)
```

Getting error: `'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'` with this traceback

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 884, in _setup_query
    self.query.add_fields(self.field_names, True)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1580, in add_fields
    name.split(LOOKUP_SEP), opts, alias, False, allow_m2m,

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to unpack the tuple:

```
qs_new = Model_Name.objects.all().values(*col_name)
```

This will pass the column names as `values('a', 'b', 'c')` directly instead of `values(('a', 'b', 'c'))`. Hence that is why you're currently getting the error that `split()` can't be called on a tuple.